# "this" variable in object method is global object when called by .then()

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I am new to promises but my understanding was that the arguments to .then() were 2 functions (optionally) to handle onfulfilled and onreject. These functions can return a value, a promise or throw an error.

I have also seen examples where the fulfillment functions are functions defined elsewhere such as:

```
function onFulfill(){...}
promise.then(onFulfill)
```

I am attempting to have a custom object which has some functions which can be these onFulfill etc functions see the example below.

```
function Test() {
    this.value = "something"
}

Test.prototype.makePromise = function() {
    console.log(this)
    return Promise.resolve();
};

Test.prototype.test = function() {
    console.log(this)
};

var T = new Test();

T.test()

var P = Promise.resolve().then(T.makePromise)
```

My problem arises because when I call T.test() the printed "this" is as expected. But when I pass the T.makePromise to the .then() function it prints out the global object as "this" and I don't understand why this would be the case.

I know I can get it to work by doing something like:

```
var P = Promise.resolve().then(()=>{return T.makePromise()})
```

But I don't understand why I should have to do that.

Thank you. I'm sorry if this is a terribly basic question. Also not that I think this matters but I am using this from node.

Comment: It obvious that `then` rebinds its callback's `this` to the global object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are passing the function reference, it **loses its connection** to the object `T`. You are not passing `T` + `makePromise`, but `makePromise` as if it was a standalone function. Thus `T` cannot be `this` any more in the calling context.

Just write it that way:

```
const P = Promise.resolve().then(() => T.makePromise())
```

Now, when calling `makePromise`, `T` is available on the scope and automatically bound to `this`.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like

```
var P = Promise.resolve().then(T.makePromise.bind(T))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is mostly a question about `this`.  Because the `then` function is what is invoking the calling of `T.makePromise`, the call site is no longer the context of `Test` but is the global context.

`this` is a reflection of whatever the context is that invoked the function using `this`.  Once you pass that off to async land, you don't have control over what `this` will be unless you `bind` it before-hand.